# Function not found error: Name: [get].; Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]

Tags: firebase, permissions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, user-roles

I'm trying to write Firestore rules that will need to get the User from the 'users' collection in the database, then get her/his corresponding Permissions object from the 'permissions' collection.

Here's how the database looks:

In the users collection I have this entry:

```
{
    id: 'USER_ID',
    permissionsId: 'PERMISSIONS_1'
}
```

In the permissions collection I have this entry:

```
{
    id: 'PERMISSIONS_1',
    content: {
        view: true,
        create: false,
        update: false,
        delete: false,
    }
}
```

And these are my rules:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function userPermissionsId() {
       return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/USER_ID).data.permissionsId;
    }

    function userPermissions(id) {
       return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/permissions/$(id)).data;
    }

    function getPermission(profileId, dataType, action) {
        return userPermissions(profileId)[dataType][action];
    }

    match /{collection}/{document=**} {

        // The below code returns true:
        // allow read: if userPermissionsId() == 'PERMISSIONS_1'
        // The above proves that the function userPermissionsId() is working properly and returning the permissions ID.

        // The below code also returns true:
        // allow read: if getPermission('PERMISSIONS_1', 'content', 'view');
        // The above proves that the function getPermission() is working properly when receiving a correct ID.

        // HOWEVER!! Combining the 2 won't work:
        allow read: if getPermission(userPermissionsId(), 'content', 'view');
        // This will throw the below error in the simulator.

    }
  }
}
```

Error when trying to simulate:

**Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [9], column [15]. Function not found error: Name: [get].; Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]**

Comment: Is `USER_ID` the key or just the `id` field inside the object?